# env reporting environment variables starting with exclamation mark (MSYS2/MINGW64)?

Tags: environment-variables, mingw-w64, msys2

I try to keep my MSYS2/MINGW64 (Windows 10) install updated. Recently, I noticed that a CMake project of mine fails to compile, and it seems it is because it starts including some irrelevant directories.

So, I took at look at what `env` reports - and I noticed these two, for me strange, entries - that start with an exclamation mark; here is the output of `env` in a MINGW64 `bash` shell (and the MSYS2 `env` has the exact same first four lines of output):

```
$ env
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
!::=::\
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
!C:=C:\Users\user\Desktop
...
```

I don't think I've ever seen environment variables named `!::` (exclamation mark - colon - colon) or `!C:` (exclamation mark - C - colon). Note also, that the `!C:` variable seems to point to the directory where the MINGW64 or MSYS2 shell got opened first (because if I `cd` to another working directory, the `!C:` variable remains the same).

So, my question is - what is the meaning of these variables that start with an exclamation mark; and what might have inserted them there? (I don't recall seeing them earlier, so I'm suspecting something Windows related, either Windows update or MSYS2 update - as I doubt the Linux/`bash` side of things needs any variable being called `!C:`)

---

EDIT: Found there is something called "indirect expansion" https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41292/variable-substitution-with-an-exclamation-mark-in-bash - however that holds for parameters, that is env vars on the right hand side of the assignment, *not* for variable names ??!!

Comment: I don't think those are new, I've seen them a while ago and didn't have any issues. While I also wonder what those a for, this smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/353058). Perhaps you should post another question about the actual issues you're having with your CMake project?

Answer (score 0):

On my system only one has an exclamation mark prefix:

```
elvish> env
!C:=C:\Users\krade
```

These env vars are inherited from Windows. It's a mechanism used by the Win32 API; not MSYS2/Cygwin. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251174/strange-environment-variable-in-cygwin for details. Just ignore them.